# How can I achieve dragging on frame within Absolutelayout

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a frame in absolutelayout as shown below. I would like that user to be able drag and relocate this frame on the screen. I tried to implement a pan gesture but unfortunately it doesnt work as expected. Can somebody show me the correct way? Is it possible without using any 3rd party library?

```
<AbsoluteLayout>

        <Frame x:Name="frm"  Padding="1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0,0.3,0.3"  IsVisible="{Binding IsSmallTimerVisible}" >
            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="OnPanUpdated" />
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            <shared:_customControl/>
        </Frame>

Grid  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.1*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="0.3*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2.5*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

And in the code behind

```
 double x, y;
        private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.StatusType)
            {
                case GestureStatus.Running:
                    // Translate and ensure we don't pan beyond the wrapped user interface element bounds.
                    Content.TranslationX =
                      Math.Max(Math.Min(0, x + e.TotalX), -Math.Abs(Content.Width - App.ScreenWidth));
                    Content.TranslationY =
                      Math.Max(Math.Min(0, y + e.TotalY), -Math.Abs(Content.Height - App.ScreenHeight));
                    break;

                case GestureStatus.Completed:
                    {
                        // Store the translation applied during the pan
                        x = Content.TranslationX;
                        y = Content.TranslationY;
                        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(frm, new Rectangle(x, y, .3, .3));
                        break;
                    }

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem like what you need is a **Touch Tracking Effect**

[This](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/effects/touch-tracking/#Putting_the_Touch_Effect_to_Work) example is very similar with your requirement.

```
void OnTouchEffectAction(object sender, TouchActionEventArgs args)
{
    BoxView boxView = sender as BoxView;

    switch (args.Type)
    {
        case TouchActionType.Pressed:
            // Don't allow a second touch on an already touched BoxView
            if (!dragDictionary.ContainsKey(boxView))
            {
                dragDictionary.Add(boxView, new DragInfo(args.Id, args.Location));

                // Set Capture property to true
                TouchEffect touchEffect = (TouchEffect)boxView.Effects.FirstOrDefault(e => e is TouchEffect);
                touchEffect.Capture = true;
            }
            break;

        case TouchActionType.Moved:
            if (dragDictionary.ContainsKey(boxView) && dragDictionary[boxView].Id == args.Id)
            {
                Rectangle rect = AbsoluteLayout.GetLayoutBounds(boxView);
                Point initialLocation = dragDictionary[boxView].PressPoint;
                rect.X += args.Location.X - initialLocation.X;
                rect.Y += args.Location.Y - initialLocation.Y;
                AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(boxView, rect);
            }
            break;

        case TouchActionType.Released:
            if (dragDictionary.ContainsKey(boxView) && dragDictionary[boxView].Id == args.Id)
            {
                dragDictionary.Remove(boxView);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

> The Pressed logic sets the Capture property of the TouchEffect object
>   to true. This has the effect of delivering all subsequent events for
>   that finger to the same event handler.
>
> The Moved logic moves the BoxView by altering the LayoutBounds
>   attached property. The Location property of the event arguments is
>   always relative to the BoxView being dragged, and if the BoxView is
>   being dragged at a constant rate, the Location properties of the
>   consecutive events will be approximately the same. For example, if a
>   finger presses the BoxView in its center, the Pressed action stores a
>   PressPoint property of (50, 50), which remains the same for subsequent
>   events. If the BoxView is dragged diagonally at a constant rate, the
>   subsequent Location properties during the Moved action might be values
>   of (55, 55), in which case the Moved logic adds 5 to the horizontal
>   and vertical position of the BoxView. This moves the BoxView so that
>   its center is again directly under the finger.
>
> You can move multiple BoxView elements simultaneously using different
>   fingers.